# SQL combining multiple tables of different sizes

Tags: sql, sql-server

As it stands with my query I am generating 4 tables as a result. I would like to merge these into one within the query. Here's a general example of what I'm looking to do.

```
Table_1 (largest)
+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
|Col_1     |Col_2     |Col_3     |Col_4     |Col_5     |
+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
|  A1      |  B1      |  C1      |  D1      |  E1      |
+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
|  A2      |  B2      |  C2      |  D2      |  E1      |
+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
|  A3      |  B2      |  C3      |  D3      |  E2      |
+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
|  A4      |  B3      |  C4      |  D4      |  E3      |
+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+

Table_2 (2nd largest)
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| Col_5 | Col_6 | Col_7 | Col_8 |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|  E1   |  F1   |  G1   |  H1   |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|  E2   |  F2   |  G2   |  H1   |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|  E3   |  F3   |  G3   |  H2   |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+

Table_3 (3rd largest)
+-------+-------+--------+--------+
| Col_8 | Col_9 | Col_10 | Col_11 |
+-------+-------+--------+--------+
|  H1   |  I1   |  J1    |  K1    |
+-------+-------+--------+--------+
|  H2   |  I2   |  J2    |  K1    |
+-------+-------+--------+--------+
|  H3   |  I3   |  J3    |  K2    |
+-------+-------+--------+--------+

Table_4 (smallest)
+--------+--------+--------+
| Col_11 | Col_12 | Col_13 |
+--------+--------+--------+
|   K1   |   L1   |   M1   |
+--------+--------+--------+
|   K2   |   L2   |   M1   |
+--------+--------+--------+

Query Generated Table
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| Col_1  | Col_3  | Col_5  | Col_6  | Col_8  | Col_9  | Col_11 | Col_12 |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|   A1   |   C1   |   E1   |   F1   |   H1   |   I1   |   K1   |   L1   |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|   A2   |   C2   |   E1   |   F1   |   H1   |   I1   |   K1   |   L1   |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|   A3   |   C3   |   E2   |   F2   |   H1   |   I1   |   K1   |   L1   |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|   A4   |   C4   |   E3   |   F3   |   H2   |   I2   |   K1   |   L1   |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

Essentially there is one column in each table that links it to the next. However the number of rows is different in each table with Table_1 being the largest and Table_4 the smallest. Here is the query I am currently using in my SQL database.

```
Declare @JBank INT
Set @JBank = 26

USE
    [MSI_RemoteDeposit]
SELECT
    IsDeleted, Routing, Account, Serial, Amount, TransactionDate, CreateDate, MICR, BatchID
FROM
    Item
WHERE
    BatchID in(
        SELECT BatchID  FROM Batch  WHERE SiteID in(
            SELECT SiteID   FROM Site   WHERE MerchantID in(
                SELECT MerchantID FROM Merchant WHERE (BankID = @JBank)
                )))

SELECT
    BatchID, Name, SiteID
FROM
    Batch
WHERE
    SiteID in(
        SELECT SiteID   FROM Site   WHERE MerchantID in(
            SELECT MerchantID FROM Merchant WHERE (BankID = @JBank)
            ))

SELECT
    SiteID, IsDeleted, MerchantID
FROM
    Site
WHERE
    MerchantID in(
        SELECT MerchantID FROM Merchant WHERE (BankID = @JBank)
        )

SELECT
    MerchantID, Name, BankID 
FROM
    Merchant
WHERE
    MerchantID in (
            SELECT MerchantID   FROM Site   WHERE MerchantID in(
                SELECT MerchantID FROM Merchant WHERE (BankID = @JBank)
            ))
```

So I'm selecting certain rows from each of the 4 tables with there being a common row connecting one to the next. I appreciate any and all help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the [Join operations on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208854(v=office.12).aspx). I think you can simplify all four of your queries to the following:

```
Declare @JBank INT
Set @JBank = 26

USE
    [MSI_RemoteDeposit]
SELECT
    i.IsDeleted as ItemIsDeleted, i.Routing, i.Account, i.Serial, i.Amount, i.TransactionDate, i.CreateDate, i.MICR, i.BatchID
    ,b.Name as BatchName,b.SiteID
    ,s.IsDeleted as SiteIsDeleted,s.MerchantID
    ,m.Name as MerchantName,m.BankID
FROM Item i
Join Batch b on b.BatchID=i.BatchID
Join Site s on s.SiteID=b.SiteID
Join Merchant m on m.MerchantID=s.MerchantID
Where m.BankID=@JBankID
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the result you want:

```
SELECT a.*,b.*,c.*
FROM Table_1 a
LEFT JOIN Table_2 b ON a.col_5=b.col_5
LEFT JOIN Table_3 c ON b.col_8=c.col_8;
```

Gives you all results with some empty fields.

```
SELECT a.*,b.*,c.*
FROM Table_1 a
INNER JOIN Table_2 b ON a.col_5=b.col_5
INNER JOIN Table_3 c ON b.col_8=c.col_8;
```

Gives you all results with data in all columns (but less rows)